# directive with multiple behaviors depending on attribute or passed value from DOM

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am writing a directive, and I would like this directive to behave differently based on a value I pass to it, this value would be static. Ideally I would like to pass the value via an attribute in the DOM, like `<div my-directive directive-value="value">` or even better `<div my-directive="directive-value">` I know I could just add an attribute and check if it exists in the attr object in the link function, but is there a better way, what is the best practice here?

Here is my code:

```
layout.directive('columnDirective', function() {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    // scope: { 
    //  directive_type: '=test'
    // },
    link: function (scope, el, attrs, ngModel) {
        if (!ngModel) return;

        ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {

            var columns = scope.row.columns;

            var column_total_before = 0;
            angular.forEach(columns, function(column) {
                var column_size = parseInt(column.size);
                column_total_before = column_total_before + column_size;
            });

            if(attrs.typeOf != "add") {
                //Remove current (prior to edit) value from total
                column_total_before = column_total_before - ngModel.$modelValue;
                var default_value = 1;
            } else {
                if (column_total_before == 12) {
                    var default_value = 0;
                }
                else {
                    var default_value = (12 - column_total_before);
                }
            }

            //Convert string to integer
            viewValue = parseInt(viewValue);

            //Add total existing columns with new value
            column_total = column_total_before + viewValue;
            scope.column_total = column_total;

            if(column_total >= 1 && column_total <= 12 && viewValue > 0) {
                return viewValue;
            } else if (isNaN(viewValue)) {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(default_value);   
                return default_value;
            } else if (column_total_before == 12 && viewValue == 0) {
                return viewValue;
            } else {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(default_value);
                ngModel.$render();
                return default_value;
            }

        });
    }
}
});
```

Currently using attrs.typeOf , in my html  this works fine,but I don't know if it's best practice?

Comment: You need to add more information, your goal, what you pretend to achieve... A different behavior could be something simple, something complicate or even something that doesn't worth it.

Comment: Does the code I have added help at all?

Comment: @Melbourne2991 yes, do you want to use isolate scope?

Comment: well only if what I have done breaks best practice? Like I said the solution works fine for now, but I don't know if it could cause issues in the long run or if there is a better way, still getting grips on understanding scope and isolate scope..

Comment: checking attribute is common in link function .